# Move Buddypress Registration to index page

Tags: buddypress

I have a custom index page. I need to have the buddypress registration on the index page. Something like facebook.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can simply copy paste the content of theme bp-default/registration/register.php into your page. You can copy everything that is there on register.php between these 2 lines:

```
<?php do_action( 'bp_before_register_page' ); ?>
```

and

```
<?php do_action( 'bp_after_register_page' ); ?>
```

But, but...
you need to remove this if clause

```
<?php if ( 'request-details' == bp_get_current_signup_step() ) : ?>
```

just remove the opening and closing if statement. Everything inbetween should stay as it is. But there's one problem, since you remove this if statement your registration form will always be visible. If you can't live with that then you need to do some workaround to fix this.